# Applying a Greasemonkey script to a chrome:// Firefox extension

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

I've written a small Greasemonkey userscript to modify some `<a href...` GET parameters in an RSS feed to make it more convenient to use.  It works fine when I load the RSS page directly in Firefox with the script enabled.

However, when using a Firefox addon RSS aggregator like Brief or Newsfox, the userscript is not applied.  It shows `No installed scripts run on this page` in the GM context menu despite the script being set with an `included pages` value of `*` and activating on all normal web pages.  I also tried explicitly specifying the addon URL in case `*` doesn't actually handle potentially unexpected URL schemes like `chrome://`, but it remained inactive.

My suspicion is that Greasemonkey is disabled for `chrome://` URLs, perhaps for security reasons due to them having much more relaxed security than a typical web page.  Or perhaps some kind of sandboxing is taking place.  Is there any way I can accomplish what I want without having to resort to a web proxy with content adaptation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, by design.

Sadly, Greasemonkey deliberately [restricts itself to `http:`, `https:`, `ftp:`, and `data:` schemes](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Include_and_exclude_rules#Greaseable_schemes) by default.

You can also run on `file:` or [`unmht:`](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/greasemonkey/index.php?title=Script_injection_rules#unmht:) schemes, or `about:blank`, [if you explicitly set some magic options](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Include_and_exclude_rules#Extra_schemes).

The developers have stubbornly refused to yield on this point, but you can easily fork [the Greasemonkey code](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/tree) and remove the `chrome:` restriction if you wish.

In the source code, you would edit the file `isGreasemonkeyable.js` to add a line:

```
case "chrome":
```

just after the `case "data":` line.  (Then rebuild and install your modified extension).

Comment: That was an exceptional answer!  Thank you, in particular, for providing sources and even providing workarounds.

Comment: You're welcome; glad to help.